# python throws 'NoduleNotFound' error for a module that I'm not importing

Tags: python-3.x

This is in python-3.7.6

I have some .pickle files that store some data I scraped off a website, each file has one snapshot of the data. Now I'm loading those snapshot files and ganging together data to form a  timeseries.

I hit one file that is fine in all respects, as far as I can see, but python throws a

*** ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

which I'm not importing or using.

ONe time the file was zero-length. I deleted it and the script ran fine. But this file in question is fine, I can load it in ipython without any problem.

The code is...

```
import os, sys, re
import optparse as op
import glob
import pickle
import datetime

# and later
for f in files:
  data=pickle.load(open(f,'rb') # which throws the error
```